# Celery configuration in settings.py file

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

Can anyone explain about these lines in celery RabbitMQ in Django. Which time it will be use ?
I ran 2 tasks(addition operation and endpoint in django) in celery RabbitMq without these lines successfully. So Please explain when it will be used in settings.py and celery rabbitmq

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://localhost'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'

__init__.py :
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your tasks are still running even without those explicit settings is because Celery has default values for them as written in its documentation.

- https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html

To visualize this, here is a run where we wouldn't set the `broker_url`.

```
$ cat > tasks.py 
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('my_app')
$ celery --app=tasks worker --loglevel=INFO
...
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         my_app:0x7f5a09295160
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results:     disabled://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 5 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
...
```

- As you can see, even if we didn't set the broker explicitly, it defaulted to `transport:   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//` which is the default for RabbitMQ as stated in the [docs](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#broker-url):

> broker_url
>
> Default: "amqp://"
>
> The transport part is the broker implementation to use, and the
> default is amqp, (uses librabbitmq if installed or falls back to
> pyamqp).

Here is a run where we would explicitly set the `broker_url`. To see the difference, let's say our RabbitMQ broker listens at port 666 of localhost 127.0.0.1 with a different password.

```
$ cat > tasks.py 
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('my_app')

app.conf.broker_url = "amqp://guest:a-more-secure-password@127.0.0.1:666"
$ celery --app=tasks worker --loglevel=INFO
...
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         my_app:0x7fb02579f160
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:666//
- ** ---------- .> results:     disabled://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 5 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
...
```

- Now, the broker was set to our configured value `transport:   amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:666//`

You need to change those settings if the value would be different from the default ones. For further details about each configurable setting, please refer to the [docs](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html).

- One particular use case of overriding the default value is as seen above in the example for `broker_url`, where we need to explicitly set it to use the RabbitMQ running in `amqp://guest:a-more-secure-password@127.0.0.1:666` instead of the supposed-to-be default value of `amqp://guest:guest@127.0.0.1:5672` which would have resulted to error `consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer. Trying again in 2.00 seconds... (1/100)` if we didn't set it.

Other references:

- [Default RabbitMQ user guest:guest](https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html#default-state)
- [Default RabbitMQ port 5672](https://www.rabbitmq.com/networking.html#interfaces)

Comment: Thanks brother for giving the clear cut explanation.